# Why alkali metal vapours are widely used in laser spectroscopy?

Tags: laser, ionization-energy

I've read, that because they are readily ionized and strongly interacting with the laser light, they could be used to study interconversion mechanisms between photon, chemical, thermal etc. energy. Why the ionisation is a factor here, how does it help to study quantum systems?

Comment: Alkali metals have the lowest ionisation energies of the periodic table.

Comment: Also that single $s$ electron looks kinda hydrogen-like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alkali Metals posses a single $ns^1$ electron which is very loosely bound to the nucleus. Hence it is very easy to remove that electron and study the ionized nucleus. Apart from being a rich source of electrons, the noble gas structure of the ion and hydrogen-like structure of the atom make the calculations and observations much more easier and simpler.